# Karate callonce: don't want to outsource init vars - getting endless loop

Tags: loops, karate

I need variables to be re-used (shared) across scenarios in the same feature file.
Please find below the working way that I'm currently using.

The problem here is that I have to outsource the shared variables to another feature file what seems to be quite cumbersome for such a silly task.

I was wondering if I could define the re-usable variables as an ignored scenario in the same feature file that I can `callonce` from "myself" (the same feature file) as follows:

File `my.feature`:

```
Feature: My

Background:
* url myUrl
# call once explicitly the scenario tagged with '@init'
* def vars = callonce read('my.feature@init')

@ignore @init
Scenario: Return shared variables for all scenarios
    * def id = uuid()

# the non-ignored scenarios follow below this line...
```

**Problem:** Unfortunately this leads to an endless loop with many errors. It seems like `callonce` myself (the same file that invokes `callonce`) runs the `Background` including the `callonce` again.

Is the idea shown above possible and if yes, where's my mistake?

Or could you `callonce` without processing the `Background` again? Something like adding an argument to `callonce` or use `karate.callSingle(file, dontProcessBackground=true)`?

Many thanks.

--

The following works (but is cumbersome):

File `my.feature`:

```
Feature: My

Background:
* url myUrl
* def vars = callonce read('my.init.feature')

@one
Scenario: One
    * def payload = `{ "id" : "${vars.id}" }`
    * request payload
    * method post
    * status 200
    * match $.value == 'one'

@two
Scenario: Two
    * def payload = `{ "id" : "${vars.id}" }`
    * request payload
    * method post
    * status 200
    * match $.value == 'two'
```

File `my.init.feature`:

```
@ignore
Feature: Create variables to be used across mutliple scnearios

Scenario: Return shared variables for all scenarios
    * def id = uuid()
```

... where `uuid()` is shared in `karate-config.js`:

```js
function fn() {
    var uuid = () => { return String(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()) };
    // ...
    var config = { uuid: uuid }
    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have to outsource the shared variables to another feature file

There is nothing wrong with using a second file for re-usable stuff. All programming languages work this way.

If this is such an inconvenience, kindly contribute code to Karate, it is an open-source project.

Comment: You're right, in general there's nothing wrong with outsourcing code. It's just a bit inconvenient if you need *just one* shared variable -> then this just results in a poor readability.

I was wondering if this is actually a bug? I'm not sure but shouldn't `callonce` cache the result? So even if you call the same feature file again, shouldn't this return the cached result instantly instead of processing the `callonce` in the `Background` again?

Comment: @droptix so my stand is that it is not a bug. so you are welcome to fix the code :)

Comment: Well, happy to do so. I checked the code and the error occurs between thread lock and release...  I think it happens exactly here:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/core/ScenarioEngine.java#L1989

Maybe I really find something... give me some time to investigate

Comment: I opened an issue and added my code proposal here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1669

Unfortunately I'm not a Java programmer so I did what I could... but has been flagged as "wontfix" because it's not a priority.